# Force exerted on surface of a tank

Tags: calculus, integration

I was doing a question and I encountered this question:
A water tank in the shape of paraboloid that is generated by the rotation of the curve y = $x^{2}$
, 0 $\le$ x $\le$ x 1 around y-axis, is full of water. Find the force of the water on the water tank.
So I had differentiated force equation:

$dF=pg(1-y)dA$ and

$dA$=$2\pi x$ $\sqrt {1+4x^{2}}dx=2\pi \sqrt{y}$ $\sqrt {1+4y}$

where p and g are density of water and gravitational acceleration.
Therefore the equation of force would be:

$F=pg2\pi\int_0^1{(1-y)\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1+4y}}dy$

I tried to integrate it but I start to doubt myself on this as the integration seems to take too long. Am I on the right track? And is there any alternative ways to calculate it?

Comment: You have $dA=\pi\sqrt{1+4x^2}(2x\,dx)$ which becomes $dA=\pi\sqrt{1+4y}\,dy$. So you seem to have an extra factor of $2\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: You're welcome.